¿Como guardar archivos estaticos de todas las url en un directorio en flask?
Tengo un servidor local hecho con Flask, y me gustaría servirla en github action, pero github action solo sirve páginas estáticas. Me gustaria hacer un archivo que agarre todas las url y guardar los archivos ya interpretados por Fkask en un directorio, ¿Como lo hago?.
Estructura del projecto:

App de prueba:
Archivo server.py:
from flask import Flask,render_template;
import os;
ROOT_DIR=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__));
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="./static/");
DEBUG=True;
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"]=True if DEBUG else None;

@app.route('/')
def prueba():
  return render_template("index.html");

if __name__=="__main__":
  app.run(host="localhost" if DEBUG else "0.0.0.0", port=8080);

base.html
<!doctype HTML>
<HTML lang="es-es">
<HEAD>
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <STYLE>
    body{
      margin:0;
    }
    header{
      border-bottom: 3px solid black;
      margin: 1em;
      margin-top: 0;
      background-color: black;
      color:white;
    }
    main{
      margin-left:2em;
      margin-right:2em;
      margin-top:1em;
      margin-bottom:1em;
      border:3px solid gray;
      border-radius: 5%;
      min-height:80vh;
      padding:2em;
    }
    footer{
      background-color:black;
      color:white;
      font-size:2em;
    }
    {% block style %}{% endblock %}
  </STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  <HEADER>
    <H1><CENTER>{% block titleHeader %}{% endblock %}</CENTER></H1>
  </HEADER>
  <MAIN>
    {% block mainContent %}{% endblock %}
  </MAIN>
  <FOOTER>
    <CENTER>Autor: Dabl03 - Fecha de creación: 2024-09-17</CENTER>
  </FOOTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>

index.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Prueba Flask{% endblock %}
{% block style %}{% endblock %}
{% block titleHeader %}Prueba para generar archivos estáticos en flask{% endblock %}
{% block mainContent %}El objetivo de este archivo es ver si se pudo interpretar esta plantilla y guardar en una carpeta separada.{% endblock %}

Salida deseada:

/static-out/index.html

<!doctype HTML>
<HTML lang="es-es">
<HEAD>
  <title>Prueba Flask</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <STYLE>
    body{
      margin:0;
    }
    header{
      border-bottom: 3px solid black;
      margin: 1em;
      margin-top: 0;
      background-color: black;
      color:white;
    }
    main{
      margin-left:2em;
      margin-right:2em;
      margin-top:1em;
      margin-bottom:1em;
      border:3px solid gray;
      border-radius: 5%;
      min-height:80vh;
      padding:2em;
    }
    footer{
      background-color:black;
      color:white;
      font-size:2em;
    }
    
  </STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  <HEADER>
    <H1><CENTER>Prueba para generar archivos estáticos en flask</CENTER></H1>
  </HEADER>
  <MAIN>
    El objetivo de este archivo es ver si se pudo interpretar esta plantilla y guardar en una carpeta separada.
  </MAIN>
  <FOOTER>
    <CENTER>Autor: Dabl03 - Fecha de creación: 2024-09-17</CENTER>
  </FOOTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>


Flask en condiciones normales parece que no lo hace, aunque podemos aprovechar las funciones que vienen con flask para testear el servidor. Usaremos la clase FlaskClient que se obtiene con app.test_client(), dicha clase tiene un método que simula una petición http y entregan un objeto reponse, ese método se llama FlaskClient.get(url). El objeto reponse tiene un método llamado get_data() que obtiene el contenido de dicha url en formato binario:
compiler.py
import os;
import server;
from flask import Flask, url_for;
from flask.testing import FlaskClient;

ROOT_DIR=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__));
OUT_DIR=ROOT_DIR+"/static-out";
IGNORE=("static","media");# En mi app, estas carpetas se sirven estática y causarán error cuando lo pidamos.
# Asi que las ignoramos.

def create_file(url:str,reponse):
  out_url=f"{OUT_DIR}/{url if url!='/' else './index.html'}";
  print(f"Creando archivo {out_url}...");
  try:
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(out_url));# Por si el directorio no existe crearlo.
  except FileExistsError:
    pass;
  assert reponse.status_code>=200 and reponse.status_code<=299;
  with open(out_url,'wb') as out_file:# reponse obtiene el archivo en formato binario, asi que lo escribimos asi.
    out_file.write(reponse.get_data());

def compiler_url(app):
  with app.test_client() as client:
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
      #print(rule.endpoint);# rule vale las url registradas.
      # Ignoramos los directorios para que no hayan errores.
      if IGNORE[0] not in rule.endpoint and IGNORE[1] not in rule.endpoint:
        url=str(rule);
        create_file(url,client.get(str(rule)));# client.get simula una petición http
if __name__=="__main__":
  server.app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"]=False;
  server.app.config["DEBUG"]=False;
  compiler_url(server.app);
  


